# how to set default beans init-method by annotations in spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, spring-4

i am learning using Spring 4 by Java annotations, and i could not find how to set default init-method to all beans that belong to specific configuration, without adding the @PostContruct annotation to initialize method at all clases and neither making them implement the InitializeBean interface... I just want to do something like this:

```
<beans default-init-method="init">

    <bean id="blogService" class="com.foo.DefaultBlogService">
    </bean>

    <bean id="anotherBean" class="com.foo.AnotherBean">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

So, i want to do exactly this by Java annotations, i want to set default beans configurations on bean's configuration container. Is that possible? Regards

EDIT: What i actually want to do is tell spring to run the "initialize" method by default on all beans that i create inside a BeansConfigurations class. It means, put some annotation or something that establish that all contained beans will run this initialize method by default. But as i said before, i don't want to touch beans classes, i mean, i don't want to add @PostConstructor annotation to every initialize method for each bean class and i don't want every bean to implements the InitializeBean interface either

Comment: You can look into `BeanPostProcessor`, but can you explain your use case a little more? Maybe there is some other way to arrive to the same result

Comment: I've just editted with more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

   @Bean(initMethod = "initMethodName")
   public SomeBeanClass someBeanClass() {
      return new SomeBeanClass();
   }
}
```

You would repeat that for every bean you want to call `initMethodName` on.

You could take it one step further and implement a [meta-annotation](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.intertech.com%2FBlog%2Fspring-4-meta-annotations%2F&ei=ADfvVM6KLcv4UIyKg9gK&usg=AFQjCNGgwuT-dHEj2xb1h4B5lMyuHOKUlw&sig2=DTZd7wVxb0AhsVtUQD35CA&bvm=bv.86956481,d.d24) like

```
@Bean(initMethod = "initMethodNAme")
public @interface MyBean {
}
```

and simply use `@MyBean` instead of `@Bean(initMethod = "initMethodName")` in `SomeConfig`

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe i didn't see this in documentation. However, by this way i have to implement initMethod name on every bean i have inside "SomeConfig" (using your example). Do you know if exists some way to speficy the initMethod to entire configuration?

Comment: Your welcome! What I posted is the easiest way I can think of. You could probably use some kind of `BeanPostProcessor` along with reflection, but that would a lot more involved. However if you use the meta-annotation I showed in my answer, you do not need to specify `initMethod` for every bean. Just replace `@Bean` with `@MyBean` and you're all set

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want every bean to run its init method(if it has one) without declaring all of them in the configuration file. I think your own post has the answer already, it's `default-init-method="init"`. In side the bean classes you want to initialize, implement a `public void init()` method in each of them. They will all be called when the application starts up.

Comment: I think you don't understand his question correctly completely. He doesn't want to use the XML-based configuration via `default-init-method="init"`. He wants to use the annotation based equivalent, e.g. `@DefaultInit("init")`, which doesn't exist as far as i know.